How can I trigger my Dockerized ETL with specific filters using AWS Lambda and pass the payload without modifying the ETL code?
I have an ETL process, which, when I docker-compose up, it just starts the process.
I am using this image with AWS Fargate, and it works flawlessly.
Now, I want to support triggering this ETL with a specific filter. I want to run the ETL and have it only update a specific activity I'll specify.
I am thinking about using AWS Lambda, but after a little research, I'm unsure on how to pass the event into my existing ETL code. Do I need to modify my ETL to do that?
If I could provide the env variables when I am triggering the lambda, that would do it, but I couldn't find a way to do that.
TLDR: I have an existing ETL docker image that I want to use in my AWS lambda, but I'm unsure how I can retrieve the handler's payload in my existing code.
Note: I don't want 2 docker images where one is for Lambda and one is for Fargate, I want a single image used in both, without maintenance hassle.

I worked with fargate triggering my task with boto3 (you could use it in lambda) where we are passing parameters (our etl was running in task fargate) with
    overrides = {"containerOverrides": [{"name": self.container_name, "command": container_command}]}

    self.client = self.hook_ecs.get_client_type(region_name=self.region_name)

    response = self.client.run_task(
        cluster=self.cluster,
        taskDefinition=self.task_definition,
        launchType="FARGATE",
        overrides=overrides,
        startedBy=f"{self.target}_{self.command}",
        networkConfiguration={
            "awsvpcConfiguration": {
                "subnets": self.subnets,
                "assignPublicIp": "ENABLED",  # keep it enabled otherwise will fail to pull the image
                "securityGroups": self.security_groups,
            }
        },
    )

Then you can call this run_task with parameters of business logic and you task receive this parameters for example my image from task definition is like this
FROM python:3.9.7-slim-buster

RUN pip install dbt-core
RUN pip install dbt-snowflake


COPY config/profiles.dist.yml /root/.dbt/profiles.yml
 
RUN dbt deps

Please take account that you could have python script (etl) as well dbt in my example. I hope that helps you!!!
PD: Commands to send a container was like
dbt run --select business_logic_param

